# how to show my drop down text intead of the value after saving the form in the thymeleaf index page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

i was having spring boot thymeleaf employee form in that i showing the dropdown by getting the value from the designation table . i was having code  for the designation .After saving the form i want to Display the selected designation instead of code on the index page of thymeleaf.

this was my controller
@PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
public String saveEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model) {

```
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {  
          List<Designation> designation = employeeService.findAll();
            model.addAttribute("designation", designation);
         return "newEmployee";
     }
   employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
   return "redirect:/Employee";
```

}

this was my index page of thymeleaf
$$$   Designation:

```
    <select th:field="*{designation}" id="designation" class="form-control mb-4 col-4" required/>
    <option value="" id="designation" >Select the  Designation</option>
    <option  th:each="designation : ${designation}"  th:value="${designation.code}" th:selected="${lastselected eq designation.code}" th:text="${designation.field}" >
        
    </option>
```